# Django: Queryset returns `isinstance` instead of objects

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

i was just working on a project

i have created a `custom management command` to insert data into the database for my api

when i try to browse the data in the `api` i get this error:

```
  Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `name` on serializer `CacheCategorySerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `builtin_function_or_method` instance.
Original exception text was: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'name'.
```

Here's my serializer:

```
class CacheCategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = "__all__"
        depth = 1
```

Here's my view

```
class CategoryViewset(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Category.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CacheCategorySerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super().get_queryset()
        print(qs)
        return qs
```

output from print(qs):

```
<QuerySet [<built-in function isinstance>, <built-in function isinstance>, <built-in function isinstance>, <built-in function isinstance>, <built-in function isinstance>, <built-in function isinstance>, <built-in function isinstance>, <built-in function isinstance>, <built-in function isinstance>, <built-in function isinstance>, <built-in function isinstance>, <built-in function isinstance>, <built-in function isinstance>, <built-in function isinstance>, <built-in function isinstance>, <built-in function isinstance>, <built-in function isinstance>, <built-in function isinstance>, <built-in function isinstance>, <built-in function isinstance>, '...(remaining elements truncated)...']>
```

Here's my custom managment command

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = "insert categories into database"
    key = "categories"

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        try:
            path = settings.ECOMMERCE_DATA[self.key]

        except AttributeError as e:
            raise e(f"ECOMMERCE_DATA does not exist in settings.py")

        except KeyError as e:
            raise e(f"{self.key} does not exist in ECOMMERCE_DATA")

        from database.models import Category, Subcategory

        categories = json.load(open(path, 'r'))

        for category in categories:
            subcategories = category.pop('subcategories')
            try:
                obj = Category.objects.create(**category)
            except Exception as e:
                obj = None


            if obj:
                for subcategory in subcategories:
                    try:
                        obj.subcategories.create(**subcategory)
                    except Exception as e:
                        print(repr(e))
```

i have never encountered such thing before ...

**UPDATE**

Here's my category model

```
class Category(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('category')
        verbose_name_plural = _('categories')
   
    name = models.CharField(_("name"), unique=True, max_length=150)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Can you share the `Category` model? Looks like you have an override on `__str__` that is wrong.

Comment: i have added my category model, `__str__` only returns `self.name`

Comment: Hmmm, then it looks like you have set the `.name` somewhere to something like `.name = isinstance`, and thus Django called `str(..)` on it. How does the JSON file looks like?

Comment: simple array of objects `[{"name": "value", "subcategories": [{"name":"value"},... ]}, ... ]`

Comment: this error is a first for me 

Comment: and you are sure that the import script has generates this? Not some other view?

Comment: i only have the usual imports, nothing fancy, i'll restart the project and see if the problem persists. Thank you

Comment: it's not about the `import` statements, what I mean is, does all the data in the database comes from the JSON file, or did you use other means to create records?

Comment: yes, the data comes from the json file.

Comment: okey, this thing just fixed itself ... ‍♂️